# How to make the question asking for books on academia/science not a shopping list?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope, close-reasons

[Is there a (text)book on how academia works?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/98282/14341)

I agree that it looks like a shopping request as its current form, but it is stemmed from the question "how to have a systematic understanding on how science and academia work (without having to browse Academia.SE too much)?", and I don't think that is of any off-topic reason. Isn't looking for a research field about academia and/or science will give me a systematic understanding on them? It's also hard to ask questions on science and academia separately since they are convoluted and I want to have a broadest view first.

Comment: By stating your specific requirements.  For a similar discussion, see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-references-and-book-recommendations

Comment: I agree that in principle a book request should have specific requirements. But would it be a catch-22 if the OP is required to list what they're looking for when what they're looking for is to know what they're looking for?

Comment: I don't think it is a catch-22. If you don't know what you need, how can anyone else help you? The question would then evolve about how to find out what you actually want/need? People can always give more context, what they already know, what their background is, what they expect, .... All these things would enable the answers to be actually useful.

Comment: @Trilarion I agree. It just that I've seen many book requests that only merely ask what books to learn X. I know that they can provide more information, but it seems that everyone sees them clear enough

Comment: I'm not sure they see them clear enough. We have no control how much the recommendation really helped. In the worst case we just get popularity contests/polls about recommended resources.

Comment: @Trilarion doesn't the vote number reflect how the question helps? At least in Math and Physics, I see reference requests are always in wiki posts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps we need to carve out an exception for books on the **practice** of academia, since that is (usually) an on-topic discussion here.

Comment: I agree and I'd add to the exception also books about the history of academia.

Comment: And research fields too?

Comment: @Ooker No, research fields no: there are specific SE communities for many fields, so better ask there, taking into account that they might have different rules about reference requests.

Comment: I think anything that is a reference request for a reference regarding this site’s topic should be an exception.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano sorry, I should have been clearer. What I mean is the fields, areas, branches that related to the study of science/academia exclusively. For example in my question you can meet several fields/branches such as "science studies", "sociology/history/anthropology/philology of science". I can even invent more terms like "political academia, interstellar academia"...

Comment: I disagree. A shopping question about good sources to learn about science is still not a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

Asking for a textbook on how science works is too broad.    There is *lots* that has been published on that subject, and it's not clear how  to narrow down among them.

Asking for a textbook on how academia or science works is even broader.  Asking how academia works is quite  different from asking how science works, so you shouldn't ask for  both in a single question.